# Cassandra partition key for simple queries

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to learn Cassandra and have a question regarding partition/cluster keys.

I have a table that stores data for shares, like the branch of industry, the performance the last 6/12 months, name etc.

The table looks like this:

[image: cassandra table]

-kurs stands for the current share price
-perf12 for performance the last 12 months and perf 6 the last 6.
-branche is the branch of industry.

Now i want to execute the following queries as efficient as possible (performance):

-read/wright the current share price
-calculate the average share price of all companies that are in the same branch of business.

What kind of partition key would you advice me to use?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what info you have to make the request. If you know the branch and the name of company you could put the primary key: branch as partition key and name as clustering key .

```
primary key ((branch), name)
```

That way you can have a first query with:

```
select kurs from table where branch =? and name =?;
```

and the second one you can specify only the partition key and create a aggreagate function to return the average:

```
select avg(kurs) from table where branch = ?
```

or calculate at your client code.

Take a look at [Creating User-Defined Aggregate Function (UDA)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html) and [Cassandra Aggregates - min, max, avg, group](http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/cassandra-aggregates-min-max-avg-group.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. Does this have any performance advantages over just taking the id as Primary key? I knew the cql queries for the required functions, it's just about the partition key to have performance advantages

Comment: the partition key will have an important role: it will define which node your data will be stored. Also, the queries that I mentioned above would not work, you would have to re design your data. But I think that branch would be a good approach because you would have the companies from same branch om same node, so both queries would have a good performance. But if the amount of companies in branches is imbalanced (too many companies in on branch and just a few in others) could lead to a node with lots of data and others with way less.